# Does shared clipboard not work in multiple VMs?

Tags: virtualbox

I installed kali from an image in VirtualBox, then installed guest additions and I could copy from host to guest just fine.

I created another VM from the same image (to simulate a network), running at the same time, but i can't paste into it, even after sucessfuly installing guest additions and rebooting. I can still paste in the VM1.

Is this normal ? I just want to copy my commands from host to guests.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not normal. I assume you are using a windows host, in which case you only have a single clipboard buffer. This buffer should be written too whenever you copy from a guest, and allow it to be written to any guest, assuming you have both the virtualbox setting enable for the machine, as well as guest additions installed. Please do double check that your guest additions is indeed working as intended for the guest which is displaying problems.

`Guest1 -> Host -> Guest2` is just an extension of the already existing functionality, there is nothing "special" which differentiates this from: `Guest -> Host -> Guest1`. I suspect there is something not correct with the install of guest additions for your second guest. Please investigate Guest2's behaviour further.